# Problems with generic methods and predicates

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have this generic method:

```
    public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.Query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Here's an example of how I call the method:

```
ST = testTable.Get( u => u.PartitionKey == pKey & u.RowKey == rKey );
```

I really don't understand much about generics and what I need to do is to have one method that takes the partitionKey and rowKey as arguments and performs a Get. Something like this:

```
ST = testTable.Get(pkey,rkey);
```

Is there anyone out there who knows how I could do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a function that takes those parameters and calls the first function with a lambda expression that uses the parameters.

```
public T Get(pkey,rkey)
{
    return Get(u => u.PartitionKey == pKey & u.RowKey == rKey);
}
```

If `T` isn't constrained to inherit a type with those properties, you would need to create an extension method that extends your class with a type parameter that has those properties.

Comment: I tried this but get messages saying "cannot resolve PartitionKey" and cannot resolve "RowKey"

Comment: @Marianne: `T` doesn't have those properties.  You need to either constrain `T` or make an extension method.

Comment: How do I constrain T. I think I heard about that before but not sure how to do it.  When I click around it shows T in AzureTableBase<T> if that helps. Hope you can suggest how to constrain. thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyone out there who knows how I could do this?

Yes, but I wouldn't name the method `Get`. I would do this:

```
public T GetByPartitionKeyAndByRowKey<T>(int partitionKey, int rowKey) {
    return Get(u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey && rowKey == rowKey);
}
```

I'm assuming that `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`, two properties on your domain class, are `int`. You can change accordingly.

I'm wondering why you are using generics though. It looks like an instance method, and it looks like you are invoking in some table which presumably implements `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T` that has a `PartitionKey` and a `RowKey`. If you're always doing, this what is the point of generics?

Additionally, why is this method `virtual`?

Comment: I am doing this for many different tables so the generic works good. Just need to code once. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Marianne: Then you must add a constraint that results in the compiler being able to deduce that `T` has properties `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am sorry but can give me some suggestion or something that I could look up so I will understand how to do this. I did add a comment but it seems to not be here. What I said was T in AzureTableBase<T> is what shows up.

Comment: `public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : SomeBaseClassOrInterfaceThatHasPropertiesNamedPartitionKeyAndRowKey { ... }`

Comment: Hello. I tried:         public T GetByPartitionKeyAndByRowKey(string partitionKey, string rowKey) where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
        {
            return Get(u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey && RowKey == rowKey);
        }  It's always saying "cannot resolve T" for the T after the "where". Note that I also created another class called tableBase and put that after the :.  That still does not help.

Comment: You need `<T>` after the name of the method and before the parameter list. My mistake for neglecting to add that earlier.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks this does help and now I no longer get a syntax error with the T. However I still get errors for PartitionKey and RowKey where it says "cannot resolve symbol PartitionKey"

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
public virtual T Get(string pkey, string rkey)
{
    return this.Query.Where(u=>u.PartitionKey == pkey && u.RowKey==rkey).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Does this do a retrieve of all data and then filter?

Comment: That depends on what Query is tied to.