# Generics and predicates in c#

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following code which is not working. It is saying that the values of PartitionKey and RowKey cannot be resolved. I hope that there is some expert out there who can give me some advice. What I have so far is based on some suggestions but still not working.

```
public class BaseTable
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AzureTableBase<T> : IAzureTable<T>
    {

     // This method gives the errors. The idea of this method is that instead of 
     // supplying the predicate you can just supply a value for partitionkey and
     // rowkey as parameters. The problem is that it doesn't work and give the 
     // following syntax errors:
     //
     // Cannot resolve symbol PartitionKey
     // Cannot resolve symbol RowKey
     public virtual T Get<T>(string pkey, string rkey) where T : BaseTable
     {
         var a = this.Query.Where(u => u.PartitionKey == pkey && u.RowKey == rkey);
     }

     //  Following method works:
     public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
     {
         return this.Query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
     }

     public virtual IQueryable<T> Query
     {
        get
        {
            TableServiceContext context = CreateContext();
            return context.CreateQuery<T>(TableName).AsTableServiceQuery();
        }
     }

}
```

Below is an example of how I currently call the second Get function:

```
SubTest = testTable.Get(u => u.PartitionKey == "XX" & u.RowKey == "YY")
```

What I want is to be able to call it like this:

```
SubTest = testTable.Get("XX","YY")
```

Comment: The actual error message would be helpful.  It's hard to say without more information. Off the bat I'd wonder what the type of `this.Query` is, as its the one that seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: what is "this"? Is "Get" a method of BaseTable?

Comment: Is this.Query defined as an IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: It's not clear to me what 'this' is referring to in the method.  Is Get<T> a method of BaseTable, or another class?

Comment: I wonder who would upvote this, you can't get much worse questions...

Comment: You asked for the error message but it's there in the question: "Cannot resolve symbol PartitionKey", "Cannot resolve symbol RowKey". Please remember that this is the code that was given to me by I think three others on Stack Overflow. It's not my code I am just trying to get it working and the others are no longer responding to my questions.

Comment: Why did you post under a different username than you did for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733864/problems-with-generic-methods-and-predicates/6733937#6733937

Comment: Because I can't get back to using my nickname from my laptop now that I am at home. I already mentioned a few times that what I have is based on others suggestions. Not like I am trying to trick anyone. All I need is some help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If that's your exact code, you can't have free-floating functions, you need to put your `Get<T>` in a class, one that preferably has a `Query` field of sorts.

Based on your updated post and your complete refusal of posting a complete piece of code, I can only assume you don't truly care (or even understand) what your code does, only that it compiles. On that note,

```
public abstract class AzureTableBase<T> : IAzureTable<T> where T : BaseTable
{
     // don't need to re-generalize this function, T is already inherited from your class
     public virtual T Get(string pkey, string rkey)
     {
         var a = this.Query.Where(u => u.PartitionKey == pkey && u.RowKey == rkey);
         return a.FirstOrDefault();     // again, only guessing.
     }

     public virtual IQueryable<T> Query
     {
        get
        {
            TableServiceContext context = CreateContext();
            return context.CreateQuery<T>(TableName).AsTableServiceQuery();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: @MIMI, no you didn't, still no mention of what `Query` is supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry. I updated but didn't directly update for your question. I just added what I think you were asking. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Blindy. By the way I would be happy to post all of the code. The only thing is that the class is large and I just wanted to post what people would I thought need to see. I added in the code that you added for the Get method. Unfortunately I still get the same errors where it says "Can't resolve symbol PartitionKey", "Can't resolve symbol RowKey" and now "Can't resolve symbol "FirstOrDefault"

Comment: @MIMI, what people would like to see is how you call your function and all the fields/methods that get called from there. None of us can *guess* your code... Well we can, it just might not look like you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to return some sort of collection, probably an `IQueryable`:

```
this.Query.Where(u => u.PartitionKey == pkey && u.RowKey == rkey);
```

Your method claims to be returning a value of type `T`, which in this case is constrained to be `BaseTable` (or possibly a subclass). Those two types are not compatible.

Comment: If `BaseTable` is just a class that doesn't inherit from anything else this hasn't a prayer of working as written.

Comment: This was added after a suggestion by another member here on stackoverflow. They suggested that if I put that class there with the members PartitionKey and RowKey then I won't get the errors. I'm open to any other suggestions. It was also suggested that I put TableServiceEntity class there. Either way it still doesn't help with stopping the syntax errors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Blindly is correct but there is one other piece... Does the T or Type return by `context.CreateQuery<T>(TableName).AsTableServiceQuery();` actually inherit from BaseTable?

Example

```
class OneOfYourTables : BaseTable
{

}
```

If it doesn't then that is your problem.